# Puzzling behaviour using jQuery Ui Sortable: using the cancel option will cause SELECT element to not drop down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmkr80Lq/1/) I have a simple `UL`, with one of the `LI`'s containing a `SELECT` element. If I use the `cancel` attribute on the jquery-ui `sortable()` function call then the drop down will not work. If I comment it out, it does. The drag and drop functionality works as expected either way.
Is this a bug or (more likely) is there something I need to do to the html or code to make it work?

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    //With this following line commented out, the select element will drop down. Otherwise the select will not display the drop down options.
    //cancel: ".fixed"    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not a sortable guru, but i think the issue is that it's being overly greedy in what it is trying to apply the draggable functionality to, including the select and that was overriding the default select dropdown behavior.

at any rate, it looks like explicitly telling the sortable plugin which items to attach to solves the issue, example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udyeLar8/)

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    items: "li"
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike...I used your fiddle to uncomment the cancel attribute (I need it so that some items are not moveable) and it worked. I then realised that there was no comma between the `cancel` and `items` attribute; I added the comma and then it stopped working again. Removing the comma makes it work as required. Surely the absence of the comma should throw a compile error or at least fail to set one or both of the options?! #confused `$("#sortable").sortable({   
    cancel: "li.fixed"
    items: "li"
});`

Comment: IGNORE ABOVE COMMENT - sorry! It still didn't work. However, by editing your items attribute with a `not` selector, I was able to get the desired effects: `$("#sortable").sortable({   
    //cancel: "li.fixed"
    items: "li:not(.fixed)"
});` Perhaps this is the workaround for me?